# HTML Form sending values with jQuery Ajax to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, fuelphp

i have this HTML form that sends input values using jquery ajax to php. The process went well, but only if i see it when i right-click>inspect element>network>header .unfortunately the real page stays still.

is there anyway i did it wrong? please help. Thanks all i really appreciate the help.

- i didnt include the full codes, cause i think i've messed up on the jquery ajax, because apparently the process went well and showed correct result

**HTML FORM**

```
<div class="product-filter-type">
                    <input type="radio" class="checkFilter"  id="filterAllTV" name="typeTV" value="AllTV" checked><label class="filterType" for="filterAllTV">All TV</label><br/>
                    <input type="radio" class="checkFilter"  id="filterFHDTV" name="typeTV" value="FHD"><label class="filterType" for="filterFHDTV">FHD/HD</label><br/>
                    <input type="radio" class="checkFilter"  id="filter4K" name="typeTV" value="FOURK"><label class="filterType" for="filter4K">4K</label>
                </div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY/AJAX**

```
var type;


    $('input[name="typeTV"]').click(function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked'))
        {
            type = $('input[name="typeTV"]:checked').val();
            sendType(type);
        }
    });



function sendType(type){

    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'POST', 
        url: "{{ base_url() }}product",
        data: { 
            'type' : type
        },
        success: {}
    });
```

**PHP (FUELPHP)**

```
public function action_product() {

    $this->set_meta_info($this->_meta_slug);

    $input_data = \Input::param();

    if(count($input_data) > 0){

        $this->_filter($input_data);

    }else{

        $this->_data_template['product'] = \Product\Productutil::get_product_data();
        $this->_data_template['AllTV'] = 'checked';

    }

    return \Response::forge(\View::forge('pages::frontend/product_list.twig', $this->_data_template, FALSE));
}

private function _filter($input_data) {

    $this->set_meta_info($this->_meta_slug);

    if (count($input_data) > 0) {

        $type       = isset($input_data['type']) ? $input_data['type'] : null;


        if ($type){

            $this->_data_template['product'] = \Pages\Filterutil::get_type_product($type);
            $this->_data_template[$type] = 'checked';

        }elseif { ... }

        return $this->_data_template;
    }

}
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? All your code does is send the AJAX request and doesn't do anything in the callback, so nothing in the UI would change.

Comment: Define your question?

Comment: In your dev tools you should see a xhr request, the main page doesn't change its headers

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Thank you, yeah i noticed earlier i have to write some codes in the "success: function(){ .. }" right? . I added this in "success: function(data){ ..}  earlier just to see what i got "var ok = JSON.parse(data);
                alert('Data: '+ok);" but there's some errors: VM2311:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0. I clearly have no idea, and you could tell. Would you please spare me your 2 cents? tq

Comment: That error means that the URL you're calling is returning HTML, not JSON. Check the response text of the request in the console to see exactly what is being returned. Normally it's a 404 or 500 error page.

Comment: ok got it...thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got it.

I've added

```
$this->_filter($input_data);
        return json_encode($this->_data_template['product']);
```

on the PHP part and added,

```
success: function (response) {

            var json = $.parseJSON(response);

            for (idx= 0; idx< json.length; idx++) {

                ....

            }
        }
    });
```

Thank you all, appreciate it. How to close this question?